# String to Date conversion does not retain UTC date

Tags: mongodb

I have document in a collection with a date stored as string which I need to convert to date data type

```
{
    "billNumber":"B123" 
    "generatedOn" : "2020-07-28T00:00:00Z"
}
```

when I try to convert this to the date using the following code

```
db.bills.find
(
    {"billNumber":"B123" }).forEach(function(data)
        { 
            data.generatedOn= ISODate(data.generatedOn)
            db.bills.save(data);
        }   
);
```

The system saves the date in the date datatype as

```
2020-07-27T20:00:00-04:00
```

My questions are

- Why does the date include -4 hour time difference. I'm in EST.
- What should the code be so that the date is saved is `"2020-07-28T00:00:00"`
- How can I add 4 hours to `2020-07-27T20:00:00-04:00`? This is an alternative I will have to use to correct the date.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sounds like your application is using local time. Look up how to work with UTC times in javascript.

Comment: Also do not confuse how your application shows your times with what is stored in MongoDB. It is possible the times are in fact stored as UTC correctly.

Comment: Thank you. @D.SM. I'm not using javascript. I'm running commands in the mongo gui. I did check the raw data and confirmed that the date is getting saved as UTC -4.

Comment: MongoDB stores times in UTC, it cannot "store as UTC -4".

Comment: Sounds like your times are simply rendered in local time by the shell, what problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @D.SM The issue arose out of a defect where the date was showing as UTC-4 in the UI created in Java. I did find the cause that I have documented in the answer that I marked below. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see `2020-07-27T20:00:00-04:00` then it is because your **client** application **displays** the datetime in your local time zone. Which client do you use? There is no "mongo gui tool".

You have the native `monogo` command shell, there is works as expected:

```
admin@so> db.bills.insertOne({
...    billNumber: "B123",
...    generatedOn: "2020-07-28T00:00:00Z"
... })
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedId" : ObjectId("5f22585fb8ea3f41ce15fd78")
}
admin@so> db.bills.find({ billNumber: "B123" }).forEach(function (data) {
...    data.generatedOn = ISODate(data.generatedOn);
...    db.bills.save(data);
... });
admin@so> db.bills.find({}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f22585fb8ea3f41ce15fd78"),
        "billNumber" : "B123",
        "generatedOn" : ISODate("2020-07-28T00:00:00Z")
}
```

If you like to **output** the date in specific format or time zone use [$dateToString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I used nosqlbooster that showed 

{

  "billnumber":"B123"
   "invoiceDate" : ISODate("2020-07-27T20:00:00.000-04:00"),
}

mongodb compass, shows the date properly


{
  "billNumber": "B123",
  "invoiceDate": {
                            "$date": "2020-07-28T00:00:00Z"
                          }
}

Comment: In interest of completeness, I did figure out how to add 4 hours to date using this (which was not required ultimately)

````db.bills.find
(
    {"billNumber":"B123" }).forEach(function(data)
        { 
            data.generatedOn= new Date(data.generatedOn.getTime() + (4*60*60*1000))
            db.bills.save(data);
        }   
);````

Comment: But you know that you actually changed the date value. `2020-07-28T00:00:00Z` and `2020-07-27T20:00:00-04:00` are exactly the same moment. I guess  `2020-07-28T00:00:00Z`  was wrongly inserted.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that MongoDB does not store any kind of internal timezone with its dates/timestamps.  Rather, it stores all timestamps internally in UTC format.   So your input timestamp in EST (New York) is being converted to UTC time (London) by shifting by 4 hours.  Mongo would perform this conversion to all incoming timestamps, using the hint of the remote timezone provided by your Mongo driver.

The way to go here therefore is to just assume that internally all timestamps are stored in UTC time.  Another option here would be to manually store the original timezone in the JSON.  Then, your application may piece together the offset in your code.

Comment: Thank you. But my timestamp `"2020-07-28T00:00:00Z" ` is in UTC to begin with (the Z denotes zulu time) which is why I was not expecting the conversion to EST. I can't store the timestamp in the collection unfortunately.

Comment: Mongo is assuming that whatever timestamp you pass in is in the timezone of your machine, and is therefore converting to UTC.  Don't convert on your end before sending.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. That makes sense and it answers my first question  The conversion from String to Date time is a necessity since the datatype needs to be Date for the client applications to work correctly. I'm trying to figure out how to add the four hours to the date to fix this but am struggling with the syntax.

Comment: Well that depends on the particular programming language you are using.

Comment: I'm doing this using the mongo queries in the mongo gui tool